# Cubevalue in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a SSAS cube with dates and a measure `sales`.

I'm trying to extract the total value from `2018-01-02` to `2018-01-26` using `CUBEVALUE` in Excel, but I can't seem to get the range to work with the function.

Using MDX if I want a date range I use:

```
Periode.Date.&[2018-01-02]:Periode.Date.&[2018-01-26].
```

This is what I've tried in Excel:

```
=CUBEVALUE("Sales";"[Periode].[Dato].&[2018-01-02]:[Periode].[Dato].&[2018-01-26]";"[Measures].[sales]")
```

This returns no result. Is there a way to choose a date range using the `CUBEVALUE` function?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the date range as a `CUBESET`

```
=CUBEVALUE("Sales";CUBESET("Sales";"[Periode].[Dato].&[2018-01-02]:[Periode].[Dato].&[2018-01-26]";"(My Date Range)");"[Measures].[sales]")
```